# python shell command pipes grep no results

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to get a domain name from a cpanel user in python.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
user = "testuser"
getuserdata = 'cat /var/cpanel/users/' + user
getdnsline = 'grep "DNS="'
test = 'wc -l'

userdataprocess = subprocess.Popen(getuserdata.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

testprocess = subprocess.Popen(test.split(), stdin=userdataprocess.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

test, error = testprocess.communicate()
print(test)

dnslineprocess = subprocess.Popen(getdnsline.split(), stdin=userdataprocess.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

website, error = dnslineprocess.communicate()
print(website.decode('utf-8').splitlines())
```

my output is:

```
b'60\n'
[]
```

So this means, that the wc -l command gives back 60 lines. So passing the output of the first getuserdata command to the wc -l command works.

However, the grep command always return blank. No matter it I put in "DNS=" or "=" or even "a". The file is the normal cpanel user file, and I have verified that DNS is in the file.

When I just output the data from the first process userdataprocess I can manually check for the DNS entry.

Do I have to do anything different when using the grep command in this fashion?

Comment: `userdataprocess.stdout` is empty when `dnslineprocess` runs, because `testprocess` consumed all of it already.  I'm not aware of a simple workaround for that - but your use of `subprocess` is entirely unnecessary anyway: everything you're doing with it (reading a file, counting lines, checking for specific text in those lines) is trivially doable in Python directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script fails because of the quotes around `DNS=`.

You can use `shell=True` to make the script work:

```py
dnslineprocess = subprocess.Popen(getdnsline, stdin=userdataprocess.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Source: [Passing double quote shell commands in python to subprocess.Popen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928860/passing-double-quote-shell-commands-in-python-to-subprocess-popen)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `testprocess.communicate()` for the `wc -l` command already consumes all of the output of `userdataprocess.stdout` and closes it in fact, so there's nothing left for `dnslineprocess.communicate()` to read.

You should instead read the output of `userdataprocess.stdout` into a variable and then use it as an input to both `testprocess.communicate()` and `dnslineprocess.communicate()`.

Also, as @pyb pointed out, you are unnecessarily quoting `DNS=` in your `grep` command, which, without a shell, will be passed to `grep` with double quotes included as part of the string to filter with. You should simply remove them as there are no special characters in your filter string.

```
import subprocess
user = "testuser"
getuserdata = 'cat /var/cpanel/users/' + user
getdnsline = 'grep DNS='
test = 'wc -l'

userdataprocess = subprocess.Popen(getuserdata.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

userdata = userdataprocess.stdout.read()

testprocess = subprocess.Popen(test.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

test, error = testprocess.communicate(userdata)
print(test)

dnslineprocess = subprocess.Popen(getdnsline.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

website, error = dnslineprocess.communicate(userdata)
print(website.decode('utf-8').splitlines())
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I thought of it too and commented the parts that call `wc -l` and got the same results.

Comment: It actually does work, but the secondary problem is as pyb pointed out, that the OP unnecessarily quoted `DNS=`. I've edited the answer accordingly.