# Passing shell commands in python subprocess.Popen() with two quoted words

Tags: python, subprocess

I was trying to run the next command in my python code:

```
iostat -d 7 7 -p sda | awk '!/^Device/' | awk '!/^Linux/'
```

The way I tried it so far was this:

```
command = ["iostat", "-d", "7", "7", "-p", "sda", "|", "awk", "'!/^Device/'", "|", "awk", "'!/^Linux/'"]
device = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
devicetr = device.stdout.read()
```

It seems that the code won't handle the quotes marks in `"'!/^Device/'"` and in `"'!/^Linux/'"` like `'!/^Device/'` and `'!/^Linux/'` as intended.

When there is no USB connected, instead of blank I get this:

```
Linux 4.14.98-v7+   01/28/2020  _armv7l_    (4 CPU)

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
```

Tried already adding `'\'` and this:
[Passing double quote shell commands in python to subprocess.Popen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928860/passing-double-quote-shell-commands-in-python-to-subprocess-popen?rq=1)

Comment: This will not work since the `|` and other characters are interpreted by the shell and `Popen` by default runs with `shell=False`.  Shell pipelines are not easy to execute from Python especially with complex quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to add additional quotes because `subprocess` will automatically add them when needed.

```
command = ["iostat", "-d", "7", "7", "-p", "sda", "|", "awk", "!/^Device/", "|", "awk", "!/^Linux/"]
device = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
devicetr = device.stdout.read()  # also here was a typo red -> read
```

2. As @noufal-ibrahim pointer out `|` doesn't work this way. You need to pipe your commands:

```py
ps1 = subprocess.Popen(["iostat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk",  "!/^ *KB/"], stdin=ps1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  # filter out line with KB and extra space
print(ps2.stdout.read().decode())
```

^ This code works on my machine, you can adjust it to your use case.

**Appendix**. And instead of manually creating command list you can use `shlex` lib (from standard python lib):

```py
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("python foo.py 'multi word arg'")
['python', 'foo.py', 'multi word arg']
```

Comment: Tried removing, yet getting the same problem.