# Linux ignore the quotes from a command launched in my python script

Tags: python

I am trying to execute the following command from my python script, using subprocess :

```
date -s "25 DEC 2021 15:30:00"
```

This is how i am executing the command :

```
command_date = ("/usr/bin/date -s \"{0}\"".format(config_date))
print("command date : ",command_date)

proc = subprocess.Popen(command_date.split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE, encoding = "utf8")
result_date = proc.stdout.read()
print("\nNew system date : ", result_date)
```

But i am getting the following error :

```
/usr/bin/date: extra operand '2021'
```

After some tests directly by the terminal, the error apprear if i am using the command without the quotes around the date string. But my variable *command_date* is well constructed (see print : `/usr/bin/date -s "25 DEC 2021 15:30:00"`)

Do you know why my quotes are ignored and how to fix it ?

Comment: Use list instead of formatted string to pass args https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928860/passing-double-quote-shell-commands-in-python-to-subprocess-popen

Comment: @lllrnr101 If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link as a comment...

Comment: Try to print `command_date.split()` and see the problem...

Comment: @Tomerikoo This is what i got : `['/usr/bin/date', '-s', '"25', 'DEC', '2021', '15:30:00"']`. I understand why it wasn't working now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from calling `split` on the string, which splits the string at whitespaces into seperate arguments for date. Try to build the list of command + arguments yourself:

```
command = ["/usr/bin/date", "-s", "{0}".format(config_date)]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, encoding = "utf8")
result_date = proc.stdout.read()
print("\nNew system date : ", result_date)
```